# I want to access value returned from nativescript sqlite

Tags: javascript, typescript, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

i have this function that i wrote in typescript and nativescript the value for count is returned from sqlite as promise but not accessible so function alway returns false

```
checkIfBookmarkAlreadyExist(study_number:string){
        this.countInDb=0;
        (new Sqlite("sts.db")).then(db => {
         this.countInDb=db.get("SELECT count(*) FROM bookmarks WHERE study_number= ?",[study_number] ).then(row => {


            return row;

         });
        });
        console.log("value of countInDb ouside: ", this.countInDb); 
        if(this.countInDb>1){
            return true
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `countInDb` is set inside a callback which is executed after `console.log(... countInDb)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

1. Make it 'NESTED' function:

   ```
   checkIfBookmarkAlreadyExist(study_number:string){
       this.countInDb=0;
       let flag = true;//I don't recommend to make this variable global
       (new Sqlite("sts.db")).then(db => {
           db.get("SELECT count(*) FROM bookmarks WHERE study_number= ?",[study_number] )
               .then(row => {
                   this.countInDb= row;
                   console.log("value of countInDb ouside: ", this.countInDb); 
                   if(this.countInDb>1){
                       return true
                   } else{
                       return false;
                   }
               });
           });  
   }
   ```
2. Try Async

   ```
   if(checkIfBookmarkAlreadyExist(study_number)>1){
                   return true
               }else{
                   return false;
               }

   async function checkIfBookmarkAlreadyExist(study_number:string) {     
       this.countInDb = 0;
       try {
           this.countInDb = await getData(study_number);
           console.log("value of countInDb ouside: ", this.countInDb); 
       } catch (e) {
           console.error(e);

       }
      return this.countInDb;
   }

   function getData(study_number:string) {
        (new Sqlite("sts.db")).then(db => {
            this.countInDb=db.get("SELECT count(*) FROM bookmarks WHERE study_number= ?",[study_number] )
               .then(row => {
                   return row;
               });
           });
   }
   ```

Comment: this is not working the value is still false though the db return the value

Comment: My fault. Try to take the `if(this.countInDb>1){
        return true
        }else{
            return false;
        }` out the async function. I modified the answer.